# Is there a way to globally redirect taxonomy paths -- on a pattern?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 7

I know there is url alias but what I need to happen is the taxonomy path be redirected to a view. The itemization will be from a tag. This tag basically controls a views output. I want to have that terms URL be redirected to that view page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create the view and make its path "taxonomy/term/%". That will take care of the redirect of the default taxonomy pages for you. Then you'll need to use a contextual filter to provide the argument of the taxonomy term id to the view.

Comment: I was actually thinking of overriding with panel pages or context... because to make a view I would still have the original taxonomy term url in place (or am I mis-interpreting the view...?) The other thing is the taxonomy tag (link) shows on nodes pretty regularly as is so I need to control it so that after a user clicks it shows a page created by a view that is already predetermined... no need to create an additional view.

Comment: Doing this was soooo whimsical because the way panels is set up you can never tell what is what ...

Answer (score 1):

As i understand - you want to show some view on taxonomy term page. This view will take term as argument (contextual  filter) and display list of nodes related to it.

For this purpose you can use module [Taxonomy Views Integrator](http://drupal.org/project/tvi):

> The TVI (Taxonomy Views Integrator) module allows selective overriding of taxonomy terms and/or vocabulary with the view of your choice. Using TVI you can easily create custom views to output all terms in X vocabuarly.

Comment: I used that but I didn't see that "X" vocabulary ... perhaps I will give it another try... but I think overriding with panels maybe a better shot as well as I will try that too.

Comment: Visit vocabulary edit page and activate TVI settings there.

Comment: I still don't see that X value...

Comment: What page did you visit?

Comment: the one you mentioned